# Can anyone make the code in Cocoa Design Patterns by Buck and Yacktman work?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-design-patterns

I am working through the book Cocoa Design Patterns by Buck and Yacktman and it seems their sample code is out of date. When I try to run it, xcode says: "The run destination My Mac 64-bit is not valid for Running the scheme."  Is there an easy way to get the code to run?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to change the Base SDK in the Build Settings to Latest Mac OS X